# How to change origin of the custom paint in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

Code for `CustomPaint`:

````
return new Scaffold(
  body:
     new GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          debugPrint("hello");
        },
        child:
            new Container(
                alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                child: new CustomPaint(

                     size: new Size(400.0, 400.0),
                     painter: new BarChartPainter(currentHeight),
    ))),
); 


  //x axis code 
  canvas.drawLine(new Offset(0.0, 0.0), new Offset(500.0, 0.0), paintAx);```
````

The x axis code will draw line from (0,0) to (500,0), which is on the top of the box of the `Paint`. The origin is on the top left of the box. How do I change the origin so that (0,0) is at the bottom left of the paint box?

Here is the screenshot: 
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Just use the method translate in canvas: `canvas.translate(0, size.height)`. But mind that in such a case, you will need to use negative values in the y axis.

If you want your canvas coordinates to behave like a classical graph, use the method scale:

```dart
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.translate(0, size.height);
    canvas.scale(1, -1);
    final paint = Paint();
    paint.color = Colors.black;
    canvas.drawLine(Offset.zero, Offset(500, 500), paint);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not really sure how can you manipulate the origin of `Canvas` area. You can, however, apply a [`translation`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Offset/translate.html) on your `Offset` coordinates, which should allow you to place your line where you want eventually.

I have made this simple example, it may be of help:

[image]

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";


void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(home: new MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  CustomPaint _myCustomPainter = new CustomPaint(

    size: new Size(400.0, 400.0),
    painter: new Line(),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final key = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
    return new Scaffold(
      key: key,
      body:
      new GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          debugPrint("hello");
        },
        child:
        new Container(
            alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
            child: _myCustomPainter
        ),
      ),);
  }
}


class Line extends CustomPainter {

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // canvas.translate(0.0, 100.0);
    canvas.drawLine(new Offset(100.0, -50.0).translate(0.0, 100.0),
        new Offset(0.0, 100.0).translate(0.0, 100.0),
        new Paint()
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(Line oldDelegate) {
    // Since this Line painter has no fields, it always paints
    // the same thing, and therefore we return false here. If
    // we had fields (set from the constructor) then we would
    // return true if any of them differed from the same
    // fields on the oldDelegate.
    return false;
  }
}
```